# issue with byte array, I cant Shift left byte

Tags: c#, byte, arrays

I want to convert a string containing a binary number into an array of bytes.
For that, I have this function:

```
private byte[] ToByteArray(string StringToConvert)
{
   byte[] ByteArray = new byte[StringToConvert.Length/8];
   byte temp;
   for (int i = 0; i < StringToConvert.Length; i=i+8)
   {
      for (int j = i; j < 8; j++)
      {
         temp = Convert.ToByte(StringToConvert[j]);
         ByteArray[i]=ByteArray[i] << temp;
      }
   }

   return ByteArray;
}
```

I get an error that I can not convert byte to int(?) at

```
ByteArray[i]=ByteArray[i]<< temp;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Bytes aren't bits.

Comment: `ByteArray[i]=(byte)(ByteArray[i] << temp);`

Comment: `for (int j = i; j < 8;` looks suspicious.

Comment: And you start with an array full of `0` and then they only get shifted around... End result: all zeroes.

Comment: i want to take 8 bit and make it a byte, that's the point.
 Henk Holterman do u have a better solution?

Comment: Start by being more clear. Post 1 or more input strings and the expected results.

Comment: "StringToConvert.Length/8" looks weird.

Comment: _"want to take 8 bit and make it a byte"_ - But your code takes a string and produces an array.

Comment: Please show an input string and the expected output for that string.

Comment: if i have like "00001001" string,I want to build a byte from this info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will convert a string containing a binary number like `"001011101101011010101011"` into a byte array `{ 46, 214, 171 }`.

```
private Byte[] ToByteArray(String stringToConvert)
{
   Contract.Requires(stringToConvert != null);
   Contract.Requires(stringToConvert.Length % 8 == 0);

   var result = new Byte[stringToConvert.Length / 8];

   for (var index = 0; index < stringToConvert.Length / 8; index++)
   {
      result[index] = Convert.ToByte(stringToConvert.Substring(index * 8, 8), 2);
   }

   return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ByteArray[i] = (byte)(ByteArray[i] << temp);
```

As mentioned on [MSDN (Shift Operators)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691377%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), the following is the predefined shift operators

```
int operator <<(int x, int count);
uint operator <<(uint x, int count);
long operator <<(long x, int count);
ulong operator <<(ulong x, int count);
```

and the byte values (`ByteArray[i]`) matches the first operator specification which is then invoked and returns an `int` value. So, to store the `int` value in `byte`, you have to typecast it to `byte`. As `int` to `byte` is not implicit (data loss may occur), so you have to explicitly do the cast, as shown in the line above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to read between the lines and guess that StringToConvert is a string containing multiples of 8 '0's or '1's, and that what you are trying to do is convert it to an array of bytes.

```
private byte[] ToByteArray(string StringToConvert)
{
    byte[] ByteArray = new byte[StringToConvert.Length/8];
    for (int i = 0; i < StringToConvert.Length/8; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            char bitStr = StringToConvert[i*8+j];
            ByteArray[i] = (byte)((ByteArray[i] << 1) | (bit=='1' ? 1 : 0));
        }
    }

    return ByteArray;
}
```

Comment: lol i forgot the [i*8+j] part... can i ask why the (bit=='1' ? 1 : 0) part is necessary? the "(byte)(ByteArray[i] << temp)" solution is as good as your solution?

Comment: @user3531487  They are not equivalent at all. Convert.ToByte('1') == 0x31 whereas you want it to equal 0x1.